# Qual é a finalidade do "&" na declaração de tipos genéricos?

Tags: java, classes, genéricos

[Nesse código](https://bitbucket.org/Jerady/fontawesomefx/src/4d07691abe2709ae23deb626a655afd514e1a2bc/src/main/java/de/jensd/fx/glyphs/GlyphIcon.java?at=master#GlyphIcon.java-44), o autor cria uma classe da seguinte forma:

```
public abstract class GlyphIcon<T extends Enum<T> & GlyphIcons> extends Text { /* ... */ }
```

A minha dúvida é entender o significado deste **`&`** no trecho a seguir:

```
<T extends Enum<T> & GlyphIcons>
```

Pelo que notei, `GlyphIcons` é uma interface. Então aquele `&` teria o mesmo papel de um `implements`? Por exemplo:

```
<T extends Enum<T> implements GlyphIcons>
```

É isso (ou quase isso) ?

O que significa o caractere "&" quando usado na declaração de tipos genéricos?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O tipo do parâmetro que um tipo genérico pode tratar pode ser limitado recorrendo à palavra `extends`([Bounded Type Parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html)).

A restrição é feita indicando a classe de que estende e/ou interfaces que implementa.

O `&` é utilizado para separar múltiplos limites.

Se um dos limites é uma classe, ela deve ser especificada primeiro.